# Push data into JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making a Chrome app and I want to save the name and the artist of a song into a json file. I know how that can be done, but I don't know how to put in the data (here: `title` and `artist`) into a json array. We assign:

```
var favorites = [];
```

So if someone presses the star, the artist and the name of the song should be put into `favorites`:

```js
$(document).on('click','.fa-star-o', function() {
    var title = $(this).parent().find('.tracktitle').text(),
        artist = $(this).parent().find('.artist').text();

    $(this)
        .removeClass('fa-star-o')
        .addClass('fa-star');
    $('<li/>')
        .append('<span class="tracktitle">'+ title +'</span>')
        .append('<span class="artist">'+ artist +'</span>')
        .prependTo($favorites);
});
```

Comment: JSON is a string, a sequence of characters, in a specific format. `favorites` is an Javascript Array. Those are very different things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you could use [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add object to your array, as:

```
//create object
var myObj = {
    "artist" : artist,    //your artist variable
    "song_name" : title   //your title variable
};
//push the object to your array
favorites.push( myObj );
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the favorite format.  But if it's a JSON string you want, you can use JSON.stringify() to construct it.

```
myJString = JSON.stringify({artist: artist, title : title});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {
    "artist" : $(this).parent().find('.artist').text();
    "song_name" : $(this).parent().find('.tracktitle').text()
};

$(document).on('click','.fa-star-o', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    favorites.push(myObj); //push the object to your array
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error

```
error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

in code

```
let controls = {};

controls = {
    key1: new FormControl({ value: 'value1', disabled: true }),
    key2: new FormControl({ value: 'value2', disabled: true }),
    ...
}

let key3FormControl : new FormControl({ value: 'value3', disabled: true })

controls.push(key3FormControl); //error 'push' does not exist on type '{}'
```

I should not even use push, but simply add a new value in JSON Object as follows:

```
controls['key3'] = key3FormControl ;
```